# use declare @ syntax error unexpected in mysql workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql

I use mysql workbench 6.2 for my database.

I created procedure to execute query string, But it error "syntax error unexpected" for variable '**declare @str varchar(2000)**'. i try remove '**@**' in variable , but it is not effective in line '**PREPARE stmt FROM str;**'. it notify error "**unexpected str**"

this is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
declare @str varchar(2000) DEFAULT '';
set @str = 'select * from category;';
PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Just removing the `@` won't help, prepared statements must use session variables. (see improved answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are not declared. You do not need (and cannot do)

```
DECLARE @str varchar(2000) DEFAULT '';
```

only the set you already have is necessary

```
SET @str = 'select * from category;';
```

As an aside, it is best to name the session variables in situations like this something unique (in case the connection calling the procedure is already using the simple name for something else).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @dhh It did provide an answer; but I'll admit it could've been a little more verbose since it could be interpreted as "remove the @".